# how to put popup automatically open in extension page action by url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension page action that works in certain URLs with popup, I wonder if you can open the popup automatically when the User access the specific site?

Answer (score -1):

Define the 'matches' in the manifest.json file like the following:

```
"matches": ["http://www.site.ext/*"]
```

Then the content script of your extension will be loaded when the specific site is visited and you can do almost everything.

For more information refer [Chrome -> Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: That's not even remotely what the OP is asking for.